# Seeing several thousand retransmits every 10 sec. via iperf3 on TCP traffic through a propritary network bridge device

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, iperf3

What is the most likely cause of TCP packet fastACKretransmits when testing with iperf3 on a small 5-7 node Linus AutoIP network running on a TI AM5728 board?  Where and what setting should we check first?  We are running both Ethernet ports of the AM5728 processor in a bridge configuration and running the iperf3 test from a 4GB RPi w/1Gb/sec Ethernet port through the 1st port of the TI board and out to a 2nd RPi on the 2nd TI board port.

Does anyone have a list of the standard latest greatest TCP protocol parameters, linux system control configuration and initialization settings?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this [article](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/tcp-retransmission-may-be-misleading/).